# ifelse in R to determine 2 conditions; one simple the other composite

Tags: r, function, if-statement

**Background:**

I have **two elements** in an R function (**see my R code below**), `type` and `width`. The `type` element simply can be **1** or **2**. But `width` can take any number.

**Question:**

Suppose there there **two specific numbers** that act as criteria for `width`. First number is **1**. Second number is **sqrt(2) / 2**.

How can I say:

IF **"type" is 1 AND "width" is NOT 1 AND ALSO (i.e., still type is 1) "width" is NOT sqrt(2) / 2,**  THEN "**do ...**"?

Can I use:

```
 type = 1
 width = sqrt(2)/ 2


ifelse(type == 1 & width != 1 & width != sqrt(2)/2, "do nothing", "the critera" )
```

Comment: Yes. And the problem is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on what you want to do.  `ifelse()` has the slight oddity of returning something of the same length as the logical condition.  Hence, it can be great (simple) for assignment statements such as

```
a <- 1
b <- ifelse(a==1,1,2)
b
[1] 1
```

or even

```
a <- c(1,3,5,7)
b <- ifelse(a<4,1,2)
b
[1] 1 1 2 2
```

However, this makes `ifelse()` a bad choice for other things, such as flow, in which case, you're better off with something like

```
if(type == 1 & width != 1 & width != sqrt(2)/2) {
  answer <- "yes, this is the criteria"
  doSomeStuff(width)
}
else {
  answer <- "I'm sorry, but the princess is in another castle"
  doSomeOtherStuffInstead(width)
}
```

It's worth pointing out that weird things can happen if the lengths don't match up.  Such as...

```
a <- 1:4
b <- 5:9
c <- ifelse(1<2,a,b)
c
[1] 1
```

You'd think `c` would now contain all the elements of `a` but it doesn't - only the first element.

Hope this helps!

Comment: you're right, it still needs an "else".  So `ifelse(type == 1 & !(width %in% c(1, sqrt(2)/2), "wide", "not wide")` should run.

Comment: Oh, I meant if I use "wide" (a non.numeric value) for `width` can I mix it with %n%? That is I say IF width is NOT 1, or is NOT sqrt(2)/2, or is NOT "width", THEN ...?

Comment: You can kind of mix numeric and character elements of a vector, but R will coerce them all to character.  Try `c(1, sqrt(2)/2, "wide")` and see what it does, then `1 %in% c(1, sqrt(2)/2, "wide")`.  In both cases, it turns numeric into character so that they're all character (including the "1" in the "1 %in% ..."  So, yes you can do it (if I understood you right) but I'd recommend being super careful and test a lot.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing wrong with your logic (`type` must be 1 and `width` can't be 1 or `sqrt(2)/2`), but the `ifelse` statement complains that you haven't supplied an else.  Try:

```
if(type == 1 & width != 1 & width != sqrt(2)/2) cat("do ...")
```

Comment: Another way to workd your logic is `type == 1 & !(width %in% c(1,sqrt(2)/2))`